# SQL products contain other

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table look like this

```
Parent  Child
10      2
10      3
10      4
10      5
11      2
11      3
```

as you can see parent 10 also contain parent 11 and thats what I want to display in the table, I want to add to it a row with that data :

```
Parent  Child
10      2
10      3
10      4
10      5
**10        11**
11      2
11      3
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What if parent 11 had a child 7, that does not exists in 10?

Comment: Could you explain a little more. From what I see is that you also need to remove 10,2 and 10,3.

Comment: But when you have a Parent Child Relation Table, Why would you put a parent identifier in the child column?

Comment: Just because 10's children are a superset of 11's children I don't think automatically follows that 11 is 10's child. And if it does, does that mean you don't want to show that 2 or 3 are direct children of 10 anymore? I suspect you'd do better to just modify your first table with the structure you want.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Hi, no if 11 had a child 7 he doesnt exist in 10

Comment: microsoft SQL server @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Cataklysim, cuz from my side 11 is a child of 10, and he is a parent of 2 and 3

Comment: I think what you need is a relationship table as well, to define a relationship between 2 parents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get parents that "contain" other parents using a self-join and aggregation:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, count(*) over (partition by parent) as num_child
      from yourtable
     )
select tp2.parent, tp.parent
from t tp join
     t tp2
     on tp.child = tc2.child and tp.parent <> tp2.parent
group by tp.parent, tp2.parent, tp.num_child
having count(*) = tp.num_child  -- all children match
```

(This version assumes no duplicate rows.)

You can then use `insert` to add these into the table.

Note:  If two parents have the same children, two rows will be inserted.

Comment: Hi, there an error with your query with the having: Column 't.num_child' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @Dror . . . That should be in the `GROUP BY`.